# Magento : Add an additional field under order form for admin use only

Tags: magento

I need two additional fields for adding additional notes with each order besides comments...

I have trying running this script found on the web

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'backend_type'  => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'         => 'Your attribute label',
        'visible'       => true,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,   
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
        'default'       => ''
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'your_attribute_code', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

But after running and checking the order form there were no additional field beside comments.... any one has any idea about how i could do it..

Comment: You may recreate the table by deleting order registration row from resource table. But this will delete your old orders.

Comment: @gowri :( is this only a way for this... magento is robust it must have someting for this..

Comment: Yes I agree. There may be versionized db or table option. But I am not sure. My suggestion try in your trial version of magneto and deploy in your dev server. Otherwise you will get headache.